# Android Java : How to save byteArray of any file type to file

Tags: java, android, filesystems, byte, firebase-storage

After downloading bytes for a file from the server. I'm struggling to convert those bytes to file and use the file. I can't seem to get what I'm doing wrong.

**How I'm converting bytes to file.**

```
public File putFile(byte[] b) throws IOException {
      final File       f    = new File(A.getDir("my_custom_file", Context.MODE_PRIVATE), 
                                "downloads");
      FileOutputStream out  = new FileOutputStream(f);
      out.write(b);
      out.flush();
      out.close();
      return f;
   }
```

**The method for opening the file.**

```
private void openFile(Uri uri, String ext) {
      MimeTypeMap myMime    = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
      Intent      newIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
      String      mimeType  = myMime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(ext);
      newIntent.setDataAndType(uri, mimeType);
      newIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
      A.startActivity(newIntent);
   }
```

**Opening the file :**

```
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(putFile(bytes));
openFile(uri, "extension");
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT : Anyway, I'm using firebase to download files.**

```
FirebaseStorage  S          = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
         StorageReference storageRef = S.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://...");
         storageRef = storageRef.child(ChildRef);

         final long ONE_MEGABYTE = 1024 * 1024;
         storageRef.getBytes(ONE_MEGABYTE * 7).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<byte[]>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(byte[] bytes) {
               //...
            }
         }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
               //..
            }
         });
```

Comment: Well start with telling what goes wrong exactly.

Comment: Third-party apps have no direct filesyste access to your app's portion of [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html). Use `FileProvider` to serve the file to the other app.

Comment: `"extension"`??? What kind of extension would that be?

Comment: @greenapps bytes don't seem to be put into the file.

Comment: @CommonsWare I don't want to server other Apps, I just want to save bytes as file so the user can open the file now and probably a bit later. Should I still change it?

Comment: @greenapps could be any extension of the file the user is trying to download. png, xls, mp3.

Comment: `bytes don't seem to be put into the file`??? What do you mean? Is there no file created?

Comment: @greenapps the file is created, but when I try to `openFile(uri, "extension");`, for an image, it just shows no thumbnail, or media not found if its an audio file.

Comment: "I don't want to server other Apps" -- that is what you wrote in your code. `ACTION_VIEW` is going to try to open some third-party app to view the content. "so the user can open the file now" -- opening a file requires other apps. "Should I still change it?" -- if you want to use `ACTION_VIEW`, yes.

Comment: @CommonsWare Ohhhhh, I see what you mean now. Let me try to look at that.

Comment: @CommonsWare from your comments, I ended up doing what you suggested. Have a new question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40355076/android-java-how-to-open-a-downloaded-file-using-fileprovider-in-another-app