# Android Java : How to open a downloaded file using FileProvider in another App

Tags: java, android, android-fileprovider

I have the following setup, but when opening the file in third party app, the file is not being found.

**After downloading a file(In bytes), I store it.**

```
public File storeFile(byte[] b, String ref) throws IOException {
      String           path = String.valueOf(ref).replaceAll("/+", "_");
      final File       f    = new File(A.getDir(path, Context.MODE_PRIVATE), "downloads");
      FileOutputStream out  = new FileOutputStream(f);
      out.write(b);
      out.flush();
      out.close();
      return f;
   }
```

**Then try to read it and open it.**

```
try {
    Uri  uri               = Uri.fromFile(storeFile(bytes, ref));
    MimeTypeMap mime       = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
    Intent      i          = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    String      type       = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(ext);
    File        imagePath  = new File(getFilesDir(), "downloads");
    File        file    = new File(imagePath, uri.getPath());
    Uri         newUri     = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "com.do.app.fileprovider", file);

    i.setDataAndType(uriContent, type);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    A.startActivity(i);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**And in Manifest**

```
<provider
     android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
     android:authorities="com.do.app.fileprovider"
     android:exported="false"
     android:grantUriPermissions="true">
     <meta-data
          android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
          android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
</provider>
```

**Paths**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <files-path name="cloud_files" path="downloads"/>
</paths>
```

I can't seem to find what I'm missing.

Comment: `FileProvider.getUriForFile()`. Does it return ok? Please tell the value of `uri.toString()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
File        imagePath  = File(getFilesDir(), "downloads");
```

That is a completely different directory as used in

```
 File       f    = new File(A.getDir(path, Context.MODE_PRIVATE), "downloads");
```

Just compare `imagePath.getAbsolutePath()` and `f.getAbsolutePath()`;

You better do not construct the same path or `File` instance twice but use one variable instead.

UPDATE.

I now see that your code is even a bigger mess.

```
Uri  uri               = Uri.fromFile(storeFile(bytes, ref));
Uri         newUri     = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "com.do.app.fileprovider", file);
```

You are not using `uri` or `newUri` at all but instead `contentUri`. And why two/three uries? Change to one.

```
Uri uri  = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context
        , "com.do.app.fileprovider"
        , storeFile(bytes, ref));
```

And then put that uri with `setDataAndType()`in the used intent.

Comment: Ok cleaned it up a bit. Now I have this error : IllegalArgumentException : Failed to find configured root that contains /data/data/com.do.app/imagename.jpg/downloads at  android.support.v4.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.getUriForFile

Comment: You constructed an impossible path with a foldername behind a filename! Dont you see? And you did not use the code i suggested.

Comment: storeFile() will throw an IOException. But you are not seeing it because your code is a mess. What is the value of the ref parameter when you call it?